# How to access Private Repository through GitHub API?

Tags: node.js, github-api

According to documentation I can access a public repository like this:

```
GET /repos/:owner/:repo
```

But how can I access a private repo?

I created a token which gives access to all my repos and added it to the headers, but the problem persists.

My code:

```
const https = require('https');
const oAuth = require('oauth');

const owner = '<owner>';
const repo = '<repo>';
let data = '';

const options = {
  host: 'api.github.com',
  path: '/repos/' + owner + '/' + repo,
  method: 'GET',
  headers: { 

    'user-agent': '<myGitHubAccount>',
    'authorization': 'token <token>'

  }
};

const request = https.request(options, function (response) {
  var body = '';
  response.on("data", function (chunk) {
    body += chunk.toString('utf8');
  });

  response.on("end", function () {
    console.log(body);
  });
});

request.end();
```

Console:

```
{"message":"Not Found","documentation_url":"https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/#get"}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Check first if the token used is an [OAuth token](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps/) with the [right scope](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/understanding-scopes-for-oauth-apps/).

For instance, scope "`repo`", which Grants full access to private and public repositories.